# Unable to display labels inside the bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to display labels inside the bar chart using R programming. Below is the code.

```
    faults <- read.csv("/resources/data/Fault Data/Fault_data.csv")
p<-ggplot(data=faults,aes(x=Region))+
  geom_bar(fill="steelblue")+
  labs(x="Region",y="Fault Count")+
    theme_minimal()
p + geom_text(aes(y=count,label=count), vjust=1.6, color="white", size=3.5)
p
```

Want to display the count matching the region name inside the bar chart. Though bar chart is coming, count is not displaying inside the bar chart. There is no separate field for the count in the CSV file. Getting the following error.

> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type
>   nonstandardGenericFunction. Defaulting to continuous. Don't know how
>   to automatically pick scale for object of type
>   nonstandardGenericFunction. Defaulting to continuous. Error in
>   (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names =
>   TRUE,  :    arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 4816

Comment: I recommend you to provide a sample data so someone would actually be able to work on it.
It did not work because you need both x and y to plot geom_text() but you only need x for a bar chart and you have tried to include both within the same graph. Is count a variable in your Data. If not then it will never work. You have to use data functions and create a count column in the data and use it.
Did you try to use y within ggplot() and use stat="count" inside the ggplot() and see if it fixed your problem?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to plot a variable that doesn't exist. `geom_bar` internally counts the number of observations. One easy way to solve this is to calculate the counts in advance, then use that data in your `ggplot`. Please post your data so folks can help further

Comment: You could also use `geom_text` with `stat = "count"` to change the default stat used inside `geom_text`, then use the calculated `..count..` or `calc(count)` for setting y and label